# How to check json object nested key exist or not in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
{
  "data": {
    "stjCd": "",
    "lgnm": "AAA Enterprise",
    "stj": "",
    "dty": "Regular",
    "adadr": [],
    "cxdt": "",
    "gstin": "BBBBBBAAAAAA06",
    "nba": [
      "Recipient of Goods or Services",
      "Retail Business",
      "Wholesale Business",
      "Service Provision",
      "Works Contract"
    ],
    "lstupdt": "14/04/2018",
    "rgdt": "01/07/2017",
    "ctb": "Partnership",
    "pradr": {
      "addr": {
        "bnm": "ROAD",
        "loc": "ABC",
        "st": "OPP",
        "bno": "105, FOUR PLUS",
        "stcd": "Gujarat",
        "dst": "",
        "city": "",
        "flno": "",
        "lt": "",
        "pncd": "000000",
        "lg": ""
      },
      "ntr": "Recipient of Goods or Services, Retail Business, Wholesale Business, Service Provision, Works Contract"
    },
    "sts": "Active",
    "tradeNam": "ABC",
    "ctjCd": "",
    "ctj": "VI RANGE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Convert the JSON to .Net classes. Paste your JSON here: [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) and use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your JSON string to the model (the class structure). If you name the JSON's main object `RootObject` (the class that contains the `data` property), you can write: `dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(YourJSONString)`. Then check if whatever you're looking for is there or has a value or whatnot.

Comment: `Json.Net` (v. 12+) can be installed using Visual Studio's `NuGet Package Manager`.